# Red5: Save streams on S3

Tags: upload, stream, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, red5

I am using Red5 to upload a stream to my EC2 instance. Ultimately, though, I would like the uploaded stream to be saved on S3. I could transfer the file from EC2 to S3 after the upload, but ideally, I would love Red5 to save the file on S3 to begin with.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: We also need to do this.  Can tell you that using s3fs does not work with streaming!  Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "record" to s3, you may only upload a recording to s3 once the recording process has been completed. I have code to playback files located on s3 with red5, if you're interested.

Comment: Here's a link to the S3 source in the red5-examples repo: https://github.com/Red5/red5-examples

Comment: would be very interested in that, I'm actually looking for that exact thing.

Comment: @BrillPappin the playback code is in the same class as recording https://github.com/Red5/red5-examples/blob/master/s3/src/main/java/org/red5/examples/s3/S3FilenameGenerator.java